# How to read this file with java?

Tags: java, file, io

So I have a .csv file from excel and I want to read the data from it and use it.I have A main class called "Travel" that has hotels which are objects made from the class "Hotel".

The constructor of Hotel is the following:

```
Hotel(String name, String city, int stars, double cost, String imagePath);
```

The contents of the file is the following:

```
Hotel las Américas;Cartagena;4;150000;./data/imagenes/americas.jpg
Hilton Garden Inn;Orlando;4;260000;./data/imagenes/hilton.jpg
Royal Decameron Barú;Barú;4;878125;./data/imagenes/baru.jpg
Hilton Lima Miraflores;Lima;5;493843;./data/imagenes/lima.jpg
Soho Hotel;Barcelona;3;329053;./data/imagenes/barcelona.jpg
Hotel Darcet;París;2;260248;./data/imagenes/paris.jpg
Corales de Indias;Cartagena;4;294618;./data/imagenes/corales.jpg
Hampton Inn;Orlando;4;374300;./data/imagenes/hamptonInn.jpg
All-Star Movies Resort;Orlando;5;308111;./data/imagenes/disney.jpg
```

So the code I wrote in order to read this file is the following

```
try(BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    while(bf.readLine( ) != null) {
        String line = bf.readLine( );
        System.out.println(line);
        line.trim( );
        String data[] = line.split(";");

        Hotel hotel = new Hotel( data[0], data[1], Integer.parseInt( data[2] ), Double.parseDouble( data[3] ), data[4] );
        hoteles.add( hotel );               
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

The problem is that I have an error when executing this because I got null reading a line, I had this variation to my code

```
try(BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    while(bf.readLine( ) != null) {
        if (bf.readLine()!= null) {
            String line = bf.readLine( );
            System.out.println(line);
            line.trim( );
            String data[] = line.split(";");

            Hotel hotel = new Hotel( data[0], data[1], Integer.parseInt( data[2] ), Double.parseDouble( data[3] ), data[4] );
            hoteles.add( hotel );               
        }
    }    
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Even do I guarantee that not null enters the code now, my code is just reading and saving the data for 3 hotels and not all of them.

If I add System.out.println(line); before line.trim() I have this output Hilton

```
Garden Inn;Orlando;4;260000;./data/imagenes/hilton.jpg
Hilton Lima Miraflores;Lima;5;493843;./data/imagenes/lima.jpg
Hotel Darcet;París;2;260248;./data/imagenes/paris.jpg
Hampton Inn;Orlando;4;374300;./data/imagenes/hamptonInn.jpg
null
```

that is still not all of them. What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Every call to `bf.readLine( );` **consumes** a new line. So, you are skipping lines

Comment: @cricket_007  So how should I  approach this?

Comment: use `while(line = bf.readLine() != null)` and make sure that you define line before the while loop: `String line = null;`.

Comment: This code will help you. Basically, your while loop needs changed a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34474897/2308683

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call of bf.readLine() read next row. You must proccess all of them.

```
String line;
while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
   //split and proccess
}
```